# Wrapping Text in GridView without using TextBoxes?

Tags: c#, xml, wpf

I'm working on a wpf window that displays database contents in `ListView`. It works properly now, but there is one issue - text doesn't wrap. Most of similar resolved issues I found were suggesting using a `TextBox` with Wrap option on and putting the contents there but I am wondering if it's possible to do without it. Here is my code :

```
<ListView Name="ListViewItem" ClipToBounds="True" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" SizeChanged="ListView_SizeChanged" Loaded="ListView_Loaded" TextOptions.TextHintingMode="Animated">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False">
            <GridViewColumn Header="Company Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding CompanyName}" Width="150"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Company Address" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding CompanyAddress}" Width="350"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Company Email" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding CompanyEmail}" Width="250"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Company Phone" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding CompanyPhone}" Width="150"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Company NIP" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding CompanyNIP}" Width="150"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Delete" Width="50">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button x:Name="DeleteGroup" Content="Delete" Click="DeleteGroup_Click" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" BorderBrush="#FF9B5F5F" MinWidth="36" MinHeight="12" FontSize="8" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold">
                            <Button.OpacityMask>
                                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                    <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="#FFBF2121" Offset="1"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Button.OpacityMask>
                        </Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

[image]

This is what happens now. The long "aaaaa..." value in the last row of CompanyName just gets cut off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `CellTemplate`:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Company Name" Width="150">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding CompanyName}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```